# Macro com delimitador de ponto e virgula para txt

Tags: excel-vba

Olá, preciso de uma macro para que ao importar um txt pelo botão ele separe automaticamente  entre colunas, OBS: o txt sempre vem com ponto e virgula(;) então preciso de uma macro com delimitador em ponto e virgula. Tentei fazer como DaTaType:=True no meu código mas não deu muito certo.

Macro feita até o momento a seguir:

Referência: [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uj5xA.png)

```html
Sub lerTxt()
    Dim sheet As Worksheet
    Dim selecao As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, linha As Integer
    
    selecao = Application.GetOpenFilename(Filefilter:="Texto, *.txt", Title:="Selecione um arquivo", MultiSelect:=True)
    
    If VarType(selecao) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub 'Nenhum arquivo selecionado
    'Se não for boolean, é uma array de strings com caminhos de arquivo.
    
    ' Aqui é que você tem que iterar, pois "selecao" contém uma array com caminhos de arquivo.
    ' Dentro de cada iteração, você faz aquilo que você já estava fazendo.
    For i = 1 To UBound(selecao) Step 1
        Open selecao(i) For Input As #1
        Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))
        
        linha = 1
        Do Until EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, valorLin
            Cells(linha, 1).Value = valorLin
            linha = linha + 1
        Loop
        Close #1
        
        sheet.UsedRange.TextToColumns DataType:=True
        sheet.Columns().EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Next i
    
    End Sub
```

Comment: Salve, meu caro! Acho que fui eu quem te ajudou em outro aspecto desse código. Você manda o texto de exemplo (pelo menos algumas linhas) pra gente testar uma solução?

Comment: Opa, isso mesmo César! Lembro de você, vou enviar aqui abaixo

Comment: PA ;     CONTA        ;      OCG      ;      SAP      ;   DIFERENCA                 
  11;1612010 131       ; 13.998.803,23 ; 13.991.837,23 ;      6.966,00               
  11;1612010 133       ;  1.663.401,67 ;  1.663.243,73 ;        157,94               
  11;1612010 134       ;    954.412,38 ;    958.054,53 ;      3.642,15-              
  11;1612010 135       ;    260.623,43 ;    260.596,41 ;         27,02               
  11;1612010 136       ;    637.590,47 ;    637.814,01 ;        223,54-              
  11;1612010 137       ;    149.784,62 ;    151.767,20 ;      1.982,58-

Comment: Não consegui colocar nem metade do que está no txt, a plataforma bloqueia pelo grande número de linhas presentes no arquivo. Então upei no github para ter um maior embasamento dos dados: https://github.com/AlaxAtaide/Bloco-de-notas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testei aqui e funcionou com os seguintes parâmetros:

```
sheet.UsedRange.TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Semicolon:=True
```

A documentação de `Range.TextToColumns`, caso precise de algum detalhe diferente: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.range.texttocolumns

O autofit da primeira coluna fica um pouco estranho porque há algumas linhas em branco, cheias de espaços, depois dos subtotais, aí o Excel ajusta a largura a essas linhas.

Comment: Boaa César! Deu certo, realmente. Só mais uma coisa, é possivel remover essas linhas em branco para que o conteúdo da primeira coluna fique centralizado?

Comment: O problema apresentado da forma que fiz ai (Acabei de postar o código), é que quando importo mais de 1 txt ao mesmo tempo ele não conta a parte que remove os espaços, ai a coluna fica estranha novamente.

Comment: Se souber de alguma solução pra isso, por favor me falar

Comment: Sendo outra questão, é melhor fazer outra pergunta, senão fica meio bagunçado para as pessoas que quiserem usar no futuro.

Comment: Se puder aceitar minha resposta, é uma grande ajuda.